# Eclipse error: Java started exit code=1

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

I just downloaded the Eclipse Classic from Eclipse.org but when I open it, I get this error message:

[image]

I'am using Windows 7 64-bit (and I also downloaded the windows7-64bit version)

"Mapper" means Folders in danish btw.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your JRE/JKD is also 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It was the JRE that was outdated, or maybe 32-bit as you said :)